# How to understand packet lost in UDP?

Tags: networking, udp, social-networking, packet

How can I understand packet lost in UDP?
For example in a chat application if a Sentence is not received how to understand it and warn client?

Comment: Implement your own protocol upon UDP. For example you can attach sequence number to each packet. See how it is done in TCP so that it is reliable and design something which will be enough for you.

Comment: I found the following link for you, hope this helps. http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/14406/how-do-i-track-packet-loss-when-i-have-the-udp-protocol Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to safeer I found this and I think it's correct:
If the higher-level protocol that's running on top of UDP (RTP, TFTP, etc.) has some sort of identification number or sequence number or block number that is unique per packet and that changes in a predictable way, then you could display that number in a custom column and manually look for missing numbers, but there is no way in the UDP protocol itself to identify missing packets.
It may be possible to somehow mix UDP and TCP.